# Cannot access all Azure Kinect Cameras

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, azurekinect

I'm trying to use the feed from all Azure Kinect cameras in other apps (e.g. iMotions, OBS).

Unfortunately, there is only one camera available on the device manager, under "Camera > Azure Kinect 4K Camera" while the other cameras appear under "Universal Serial Bus devices".
I would expect to see them all under "Camera". Can you please provide further details on how to solve this problem.

Also, note that:

- I can see all the cameras in the Azure Kinect Viewer but cannot use the feed in other apps.
- The firmware is the latest one.
- I'm using a usb 3.0 port

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related Q&A : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/899174/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the base container ID of the Azure Kinect devices? If you see only one base container ID, only one Azure Kinect is detected. There should be one base container ID per Azure Kinect.
Best, Jens

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A look at the Microsoft link from AshokPeddakotla (related Q&A), where this question was also presented, shows that the question did not relate to several Azure Kinect but to the rgb-sensor and the ir-sensor from _one_ Azure Kinect. Microsoft only provides access to the rgb-sensor as a regular cam but not to the ir-sensor. To access the ir-sensor as a regular cam from any program/app, some kind of driver / pass-through would be required - either from Microsoft or enthusiastic developers.